# “Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS” error?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I wrote this query for a ssrs report dataset. The report works fine for single parameter value and error is populated when multiple values are selected for parameter.

@iteration is a multivalued report parameter.

```
create table #hftable
( id int ,startdate datetime, environment nvarchar(50), iteration nvarchar(50))
insert #hgtable( id , startdate,environment , iteration)
select distinct wit.id, max(wit.startdate),environment , i.iteration
from Workers wit 
join iteration i 
on wit.sckid=i.sckid
and i.iterationlabel in (@iteration)
where system_rev =(SELECT MAX(system_rev) AS system_rev
              FROM workers 
              WHERE system_id = wit.system_id)
group by wit.id, i.iteration,environment 
order by i.iteration

select count(*) ,environment from #hftable 
group by iteration,environment 
order by iteration
```

Comment: can you post the error?. Also what datatype is your parameter?, and `iterationlabel`?

Comment: @Lamak : iterationlabel is of nvarchar(4000) datatype. Did not declare the parameter. ERROR “Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS”

Comment: Then you need to go to the "parameter" definition and check the "multivalue" option

Comment: He did say "@iteration is a multivalued report parameter." however? Are NULL values allowed? And where do the available values come from? From a dataset that is mapped to `iteration.iterationlabel`?

Comment: @LAMAK I did check the multi valued option.

Comment: @NickyvV No null values are not allowed. there is another dataset iterations which is mapped to iterationlabel.

Comment: @user2974732 Then what does *Did not declare the parameter* mean?

Comment: @Lamak: Sorry I meant i did not use declare iterationlabel nvarchar(4000) in the sql query.

Comment: That's ok, but the SSRS parameter still has a type (string, for instance) that needs to be set. I was asking about that

Comment: @Lamak: Oh ok. That is Text

Comment: We need more information then. Is the posted dataset the only one that uses that parameter?, not any other dataset?

Comment: only this dataset. And the values of iterationlabel are like   'Release 31/Iteration1'

Comment: Ok, well, you do have more datasets, right?. The problem is with one of those, one where you are using a subquery, since that is the error message you are getting

Comment: The report has only 2 datasets. one is mapped to @iteration parameter to get available values. Are the other is the one I mentioned above.

Comment: @Lamak The subquery has only one column in it. I would like to use the max(sytem_rev). Is there are any other way to get max value?

Comment: @user2974732 Look, you just now changed the dataset so it actually does uses a subquery, after I wasted many comments and time saying that the current dataset was ok, and you saying that it was the only dataset, so I don't really feel like I should keep commenting here

Comment: @Lamak:The actual query has more than 30 columns, I tried to put the code in a simple way here. Missed this subquery in this process. When you said its a subquery error I drilled the 400+ line code to see if there are any and found this so made changes to the post.

Comment: @user2974732 Actually, that subquery does looks fine. But that means that you'll need to go through your code again and try to find another subquery, and so on

Comment: @Lamak: Ok. Thanks so much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

This error relates to returning too many columns in your nested query that you are using to lookup relevant values. For example, this is wrong:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE SomeColumn = (SELECT MAX(ThisColumn), MAX(ThatColumn) FROM OtherTable)
```

The nested query must return only one column for comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE SomeColumn = (SELECT MAX(ThisColumn) FROM OtherTable)
```

You don't have this problem in the query shown but this is what the error means. Maybe there is another query in your report that does this? Sometimes it takes the form of ordering:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE SomeColumn IN (
    SELECT TOP 10 ThisColumn, COUNT(*) 
    FROM OtherTable 
    GROUP BY ThisColumn 
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
```

In this instance, you can still do the ordering required without returning `COUNT(*)` in the column list of the nested query.

Comment: Latta: Thanks for your reply. The problem was with the following code IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.SYSOBJECTS WHERE  ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#hftable'))
DROP TABLE #hftable  . Removed it so the reports works fine now but could not fix it.

Comment: That's the way I make sure the table is not there. You don't fully qualify the table name in the `DROP` clause but that shouldn't give this error.

Comment: Try `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects WHERE name = N'#hftable') DROP T4BLE tempdb.dbo.#hftable` ... (Note: there is a 4 in "TABLE" as I think my proxy is trying to block Sql injection - poorly)